# Asynchronous Sockets Serialization & Deserialization

Tags: c#

I have a problem in receiving an object from my client which is written in Java.
am 100% sure of my client code and it's good.
but when i try to receive from my C# Asynchronous Server several errors come above
i think it's because the stream which i really don't know how to get it

```
int iRx = socketData.m_currentSocket.EndReceive(asyn);
byte[] receivedData = socketData.dataBuffer;
MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
BinaryFormatter binForm = new BinaryFormatter();
memStream.Write(receivedData, 0, receivedData.Length);
memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
UserData usdata = (UserData)binForm.Deserialize(memStream);
```

Comment: Exactly what error do you get? What's the complete exception?

Comment: I would look at protocol buffers for this task. Available in Java and .NET.

Answer (score 1):

What is serialized by Java will be entirely different than what the built-in .NET serializers do.  You'll have to know the format of the stream and manually deserialize a byte at time.

E.g. if you serialize an `int` in .NET, it serializes a 7-bit encoded value.  If you serialize a custom type with `BinaryFormatter`, it includes the strong name of the type in the stream--clearly not what Java would do.

You might want to consider a third-party serializer/deserializer that works in Java and .NET.  For example http://woxserializer.sourceforge.net/